# postgres/plsql generated string creates extra double quotes

Tags: database, string, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using a plsql function in postgres to loop through a large data set, and use data from each record to generate a string. For some reason, I am getting unwanted extra double quotes like this:

```
'{ ""id"": ""1""}'
```

and it should look like

```
'{ "id": "1"}'
```

Also, I've noticed unwanted parenthesis at the beginning and end of the string. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gen_blocks()
    RETURNS TEXT  AS $$ DECLARE
    output TEXT := '';
    j record; BEGIN
    FOR j IN SELECT '{ "id": "' || id ||'"},' LOOP
        output := output || j;
    END LOOP;

    return output; END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are on 9.2 you can use `row_to_json()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know, but I'm on 9.1 and can't change versions for the time being.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
output := output || j;
```

Your `j` is a `record`, not a string type. So, PostgreSQL has to stringify your `record` for you. and that's where your quote doubling happens. You don't want to concatenate `j` to your output buffer, you want to concatenate the first column in `j`; an easy solution is to add an alias for your string computation so that you can refer to it by name:

```
FOR j IN SELECT '{ "id": "' || id ||'"},' as s LOOP
    output := output || j.s;
END LOOP;
```

You could also skip your custom function and just use [`string_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

> `string_agg(expression, delimiter)`
>
> input values concatenated into a string, separated by delimiter

Something like this:

```
select string_agg('{ "id": "' || id || '" }', ',') from ...
```

That will have the added benefit of not including a stray comma at the end (which some JavaScript and JSON parser will get upset about).

Comment: Wow, thank you! I had been at it for a while and was totally stumped. I would give you a +2 for the string_agg!